# undefined method `page' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a new section in a nested page object. I defined the page object but I got this error undefined method `page' for #. Rails is complaining for the code below.

```
<td><%= f.object.page.name %></td>
```

sections.rb file code

```
belongs_to :pages, optional: true
validates :page_id, presence: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`belongs_to :pages` should be `belongs_to :page`

Also in your view, make sure that you're checking if it's nil before rendering it. `f.object.page.name unless f.object.page.nil?`